# Managing local files with Maven and SVN

Tags: java, svn, maven, war

I'm looking for a best practice for injecting local files into a project that are not being tracked with source control in such a way that the source-controlled version of the file is blind to the changes.

In particular, I have a context file with database credentials in it. I want to keep the raw "put your credentials here" file in source control, but I need to have that file filled out with the appropriate credentials for my development setup (or the production server, or what have you) without those credentials being pushed back into source control. Obviously, I can just edit the file locally and not check it back in. However, that becomes tedious over time, being careful that I don't accidentally check in the file with the credentials to the central code repository every time that I need to check a change in. An alternative approach would be to check in a "-dist" type file that each user would have to rename and edit to get the project to build at all.

I tried looking into Maven Overlays as that looked like it would require me to build a whole separate project for just my local credentials, with a pom.xml and a war file. That seems like a lot of overhead for just a couple of files. What I'm really after is a way to tell maven "if the file X (which isn't in source control at all) exists locally, use it. If not, use file Y (which does exist in source control)." It seems like there should be a fairly automatic way to handle it.

Comment: who reads the database credentials - Maven or your app? Sounds like the solution is to design this into your app

Comment: The app reads the database credentials from a Spring configuration file. This is about getting the files into the right place for Spring to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the [Maven replacer plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) a solution for your need?

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using. I created a local file with the credential values that I added to svn:ignore, and used the replacer plugin to fill in the values from that file into the template which was checked in. If it can't find the local file, it just cranks past it with a non-fatal warning.

Answer (score 6):

**Simple**

I have done this in the past, it is very simple, have a single file for example `default.config` that gets checked into version control, have another file called `local.default.config` that is in your `svn.ignore` file. Have Maven copy the `local.default.config` over the `default.config` if it exists, or have it copy both and your application look for `local.default.config` and then `default.config` if the first doesn't exist.

You can even use the same `default.config` name and have the application look in multiple places, with your `home.dir` as the highest priority, then some place else.

An ideal version of this will read all the files in some priority and use the last found property from all the files, then you could have `default.config` with all your properties, and `local.default.config` with only the few that need to change for your local configuration.

**More Sophisticated Maven Oriented**

Maven has multiple ways to get where you want to be:

1. Use Maven `profiles` to enable and disable a `property` that holds the file name you want to use and use the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) to copy the file you specify in the `profile`.
2. Use the `filter` feature in Maven with `profile` driven `properties`.
3. Use the [maven-replacer-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/) to manipulate the file directly based on `profile`  driven `properties`
4. Use the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) and store your files in your local Maven repository and pull them down from their during the `package` phase.

`profiles` are very powerful and a perfect fit for configuring Maven for different environments. I have a `local`, `dev`, `qa` and `release` profile in every `pom.xml`. I set the `local` profile to active by default, and pick the others as I need them with `mvn [goal] -P dev` which will automatically disable `local` and use the `properties` specificed in the `dev` profile.

**More sophisticated SVN oriented**

You could work off a local `development` feature branch and only have your local configuration on that branch, and when you merge your code changes back to the `trunk` exclude your changes to the configuration file from the merge. *This is actually how I would do it since, we use Git. Branching isn't so painful in SVN that this isn't an option*

I am sure there are other Maven solutions as well. Either way you solve it [svn.ignore](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm) is your friend. And Maven `profile` usage can be very powerful.

Comment: But what's the mechanism for having maven copy over a file? I've done this in Ant before, but I'm relatively new to Maven.

Comment: @jricher - [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)

Answer (score 1):

We use [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/index.html) to encrypt our passwords within properties files read by Spring.  The tool can be used without Spring as well.  This makes it very simple to keep your properties files in source control.

If your issue is user credentials, then I would suggest that you use a test account for any automated tests that you run.

Comment: I'm fine with test credentials being checked into source control. What I want is a way for keeping real configuration options that are sensitive out of source control in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think [filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) may suit your needs. You can have a local.filter that is not checked in and prod.filter that is. You can use the prod.filter by default and substitute the local.filter based on a command-line flag or local profile that developers would need to use, but deployers would not.